# making a custom cursor for retina displays

Tags: css, svg, cursor, retina-display

I am trying to have a sharp cursor on a retina display… What is the best way to do this… ? I thought it would be using SVG, but somehow, as a cursor it gets blurry… Can't figure out how to fix this…

Does anyone know how? Thanks for any help … See my jsfiddle:

```
#div {width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black;}
#div:hover {cursor: url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/ndxzsite/img/cursor_next.svg), move;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zju0e871/

Comment: Are you not just seeing high-contrast limitations of the screen and potentially persistence of vision issues? thin white line on black, moving quickly, is probably always going to look a little odd.

Comment: mmmh, I need to check again, in safari it looked blurry … Did you try the JSFiddle on a retina display?

Comment: No, on a regular display and it looked funky while moving.